# Preguntas que mezclan conceptos

Tags: discusión

Muy a menudo, veo preguntas como éstas:

- [¿como mostrar los resultados de un consulta en mysql con php en una tabla de html?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63413/como-mostrar-los-resultados-de-un-consulta-en-mysql-con-php-en-una-tabla-de-htm)
- [Condicional IF en consulta SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63368/condicional-if-en-consulta-sql) (en el comentario que dejé aquí ya se ve por donde voy).

Lo que tienen es que alguien tiene un problema de programación, y no hace ninguna diferencia entre persistencia (normalmente SQL), capa de negocio y capa de presentación.

Me mosquean estas preguntas por varios motivos:

- En primer lugar, parecen indicar un desconocimiento total de conceptos básicos de la programación como son la abstracción y la separación entre capas/responsabilidades. ¿De que sirve que un programador sepa escribir sentencias SQL y ficheros HTML correctos, si después tiene las ideas tan confusas que, a la hora de preguntar cómo mostrarlos de un color u otro, cree que es una cuestión de SQL?
- Además, demuestran muy poco interés o capacidad de trabajar los problemas; parece que simplemente "si me encuentro un problema, directo a SO".

  Por ejemplo, incluso si alguien tuviera la duda entre SQL o HTML, en ambas preguntas sería trivial simplemente imprimir los resultados para ver qué devuelve la BD, o sustituir los resultados por una lista hard-coded, y averiguar así se trata de un problema de SQL o de generación del HTML.
- Y, más importante, **no importa que alguien conteste correctamente a la pregunta, el problema sigue estando allí**. Los OPs tienen el código que funciona, los números ya salen en verde (o como sea), pero seguirán teniendo la misma falta de capacidad o voluntad<sup>1</sup> para analizar lo que hace su programa y de atacar los problemas que les salgan ("Vaya, otro fallo... sigo sin saber cómo solucionarlo. ¿SQL o HTML? Qué más da, lo vuelvo a pasar a SO").

En general, no es que sean preguntas terriblemente malas como para ser cerradas<sup>2</sup>, y me abstengo de votar negativamente. Pero el hecho es que veo muchísimas más preguntas de este tipo de las que me esperaba.

Me gustaría saber qué se puede plantear colectivamente para "invitar" a estos usuarios para que intenten hacer las cosas de manera algo más razonada y trabajada; alguna indicación a los OPs de cómo plántearse el separar los distintos trozos de la aplicación y depurarlos debidamente. De lo contrario no habrá programadores, sino "cocineros" que no sabrán más que leer de una lista de recetas sin saber realmente qué hacen<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Espero que nadie se lo tome a título personal. Nadie nace sabiendo, y yo el primero. Pero sea por tener malos profesores, o por seguir tutoriales que explican que basta con juntar código para ser "programador", el problema esta allí.

<sup>2</sup>Aunque estrictamente hablando no están cumpliendo con la norma de escribir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

<sup>3</sup>Con el debido respeto a los auténticos cocineros, que no son así.

Comment: Inicialmente, me inclino por decir "*se puede dar una respuesta de calidad que explique la cuestión de fondo*"... ¿Se te ocurre alguna alternativa más eficaz?

Comment: El ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable no es una norma, es una recomendación.

Answer (score 1):

[Adaptando lo que dice Mariano en su comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano), si deseas aportar con una respuesta, puedes responder a la pregunta y añadir mas información sobre los conceptos que el OP pueda no entender.

Esta es una [respuesta que publiqué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63751/78) a una pregunta "similar".

De lo contrario, puedes optar por cerrar, reportar, etcétera *según sea el caso*.

Lo ideal es aportar :)

Comment: Hola Mauricio, tengo una duda, en la pregunta que mencionas, ¿cuál sería la mezcla de conceptos? Seguro me estoy perdiendo de algo.

Comment: @Flxtr, allí no coloqué conceptos realmente, pero lo que hice fue intentar orientar al OP para que organizara su código, tiene toda la lógica dentro de un botón...

Comment: Ah muy bien, ya comprendo, pensaba que te referías al tipo de preguntas donde el título difiere del contenido, pero tienes razón, ese código del ejemplo que pones sin duda requiere un mantenimiento urgente :)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Las malas preguntas se cierran, las malas respuestas se votan negativo: *Vota lo más pronto posible, vota frecuentemente*.

Creo que no cerramos las preguntas lo suficientemente rápido y debido a eso aparecen respuestas. Aunque no puedo generalizar diciendo *"todas"*, con frecuencia las malas preguntas atraen malas respuestas. Construir una buena respuesta con base en una mala pregunta generalmente cuesta más trabajo y como bien apunta el SJuan, no siempre son valoradas o apreciadas por el OP.

Una buena pregunta no tiene tanto que ver con la cantidad de código que contiene, sino con la cantidad de contenido y/o conocimiento que produce. Y  aunque no puedo generalizar diciendo *"todas"*, con frecuencia las buenas preguntas atraen buenas respuestas. Construir una buena respuesta con base en una buena pregunta aporta valor no solo a quien pregunta, sino a futuros visitantes. Incluso promueve nuevas respuestas y nuevo contenido, que es al final el objetivo de esta empresa.

Pero como decía al principio, ¿puedes crear una buena respuesta a una pregunta que tiene esas carencias que percibes y que te *mosquean*? ¿Tienes el tiempo y la disponibilidad? ¿Tu respuesta va a servirles a *los visitantes del futuro*? Si tu respuesta fue al menos cinco "SÍ", ***deberías*** contestar a esa pregunta.

Y si no, ciérrala, ciérranla, cerrémosla... hay que cerrar las preguntas lo más rápido que se pueda. Y piensa que cuando se cierra una pregunta pasan dos cosas: el OP hace un esfuerzo por corregirla y se reabre o se elimina. Eso demostraría el interés del OP por su pregunta.

Invita a los usuarios a mejorar sus planteamientos proponiendo su pregunta para cierre.

Por otro lado, yo pienso que tiene más sentido votar las respuestas (up or down). El primer contacto de la usuarios con [so.es] es a través de los buscadores y ello ven las preguntas ordenadas por votos. Para que este sistema funcione se necesitan votos. [*Vote early, vote often*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/). Eso entregará a los visitantes del futuro las mejores respuestas y les dará un buen motivo para quedarse, no verán solo recetas de cocina, sino contenido de altísima calidad escrito por personas brillantes y generosas que brindan sus conocimientos y su tiempo desinteresadamente.